# Get many object from result of Oracle view

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

At my Oracle database I have two example tables:

- tabel `A` with columns `id`, `a1`, `a2`, `a3`
- tabel `B` with columns `id`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`

I have view for get information from this two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW Foo ("A.id", "A.a1", "A.a2", "A.a3", "B.id", "B.b1", "B.b2", "B.b3") AS
SELECT aaa.*, bbb.*
FROM A aaa, B bbb
WHERE 
   ...some conditions...;
```

In my Java application I want to get information result by `Foo` view by Hibernate. So I have to use `createSQLQuery()` method:

```
public List<SomeObject> findSomeObjects() {
    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
             .createSQLQuery("select f.* from Foo f")
             .addEntity(A.class).addEntity(B.class);
    List l = q.list();

    //here I want to get object of A class and B class from return l
    //and prepare return list of SomeObject
}
```

`SomeObject` is agregate for A and B class.

I have problem with get object of A class and B class from return list and construct `SomeObject` list. How can I make it properly?

**EDIT**

- table `A` have one more column `fk_c`, which is foreign key to `C` table
- table `B` have one more column `fk_d`, which is foreign key to `D` tabel

Answer (score 1):

Create a domain Class with all the fields present in the view "Foo" as below.

```
Class Foo {

    private String a_id;
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;
    private String b_id;
    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private String b3;

    // Getters
    // Setters
}
```

Modify your SQL query as below :

```
public List<SomeObject> findSomeObjects() {
    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
             .createSQLQuery("select f.* from Foo f")
             .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Foo.class))
    List l = q.list();

    // here you can iterate through the list to fetch the fields and 
    // create a own custom object as per your requirement.

}
```

**Alternative Solution :**

You can also create an Entity class for view "Foo" and write criteria query to fetch the results as well.

Please check the below links for the same :

[DB View to Hibernate Entity Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496117/use-database-views-with-hibernate)

[How to map a view with Hibernate](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-view-hibernate/)

**EDIT:**

If you have a foreign key to other table (C, D) in your View, I would suggest you to map this view as hibernate Entity Class by adding the Relationship to those other dependent entities (C, D).

```
@Entity
@Immutable
Class Foo {

    private String a_id;
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;
    private String b_id;
    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private String b3;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_id")
    private List<C> c;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "d_id")
    private List<D> d;

    // Getters
    // Setters
}
```

Comment: What if, like in edition, in table `A` and `B` I have foreign key to another enities and I would create new domain class `Foo` as you advice? In creation of custom objects `A` and `B` I have to make another queries to database to get `C` object with id equals `fk_c` and to get `D` object with id equals `fk_d`?

Comment: I have updated the post, Please check. You can consider to map your View to a Entity class in this case.

Comment: I will try it, but I have to add `@Immutable` annotation to ignore all changes on this entity.

Comment: It's not work with `@OneToMany` and `@JoinColumn` - I get empty list of object `C` and `D` class :(