# Hibernate Spatial PostGIS 1.1.1 mapping to views instead of tables

Tags: geoserver, postgresql-9.6, hibernate-spatial

On [GeoFence](https://github.com/geoserver/geofence) startup, it states that it could not find relation `geofence.gf_gfuser`.
**My schema name is geofence.**

I am using **SQL views instead of tables**. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496117/use-database-views-with-hibernate#answer-10496200) states that Hibernate will not have a problem reading from views. So why does this error occur?

Any insight would be appreciated.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "geofence.gf_gfuser" does not exist
```

**Additional config**

`geofence-datasource-ovr.properties`

```
geofenceVendorAdapter.databasePlatform=org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialect
geofenceDataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
geofenceDataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<db>
geofenceDataSource.username=<username>    
geofenceDataSource.password=<password>
geofenceEntityManagerFactory.jpaPropertyMap[hibernate.default_schema]=<schema>

geofenceEntityManagerFactory.jpaPropertyMap[hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto]=none
geofenceEntityManagerFactory.jpaPropertyMap[javax.persistence.validation.mode]=none
geofenceEntityManagerFactory.jpaPropertyMap[hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl]=false
geofenceEntityManagerFactory.jpaPropertyMap[hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners]=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `Foreign Data Wrapper` PostgreSQL plugin to connect to the views.

Since the FDW connects to a database and references a table/view and creates a foreign table, linking GeoFence to those tables instead of the views fooled it into using the tables.

**Note: My foreign tables and views are in seperate schemas, but in the same database.**